# Enable debug mode in Flask in production mode

Tags: python, flask

In bottle all i have to do to enable debug mode is:

```
from bottle import debug

application = Bottle()
app = application
debug(True)
```

How can i do the same in Flask framework?

Answer (score 17):

To enable the debug mode I would add the following code to the flask app:

```
app.config['ENV'] = 'development'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
```

I would also sugest setting environment variables for the environment and debug.

```
$ export FLASK_ENV=development 
$ export FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

If you are jus trying flask locally and don't want use one of the two methods above you can also run your flask app in debug mode with the following line at the command line:

```
flask run --debug
```

Comment: This did not help i just tried to print a variable that didn't exist and i got `Internal Server Error` How can i ensure that debug mode is active?

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος that's how you enable debug mode in flask you can check that on the documentation(http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/). My guess is that you have to either change the ENV to development or it's something related with what you have running the app.py code (Gunicorn?)

Comment: I'am running my app under Apache + mod_wsgi, not Gunicorn/ uwsgi. Debug mode didn't activated for me this way. Not even with the export values other members suggested.

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος The only other configuration I can think might by missing is app.config['TESTING'] = True

Comment: I just tried that also, but iam still getting `internal server error` :-( Why debug mode does not get enabled for me?

Answer (score 4):

If you're in development environment; you can simply specify it in your `Flask.run` as specified [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.run).

**Example:**

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8080', debug=True)
```

You can also take another approach at modifying the `default_config` as shown [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.debug).

**Example:**

```
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8080')
```

or even exporting `FLASK_DEBUG=1` - Keep in mind that `FLASK_DEBUG` overrides `FLASK_ENV=development`.

As you can see below Flask denotes the following:

> Do not enable debug mode when deploying in production.

Although as you stated you'd love to have debugging enabled on production; hence why I wouldn't use the `Flask.run` since it's meant to be used on a development environment, and I would certainly not set the `FLASK_ENV` to `development`.

I would suggest you rethink the concept of debugging on production, since production is not meant for debugging; simply put, I believe your reasoning of wanting to debug on production is wrong.

Another possible solution is to use the following (forked, multi-process):

```
from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication  
application = DebuggedApplication(app, True)
```

Comment: I want to test some things in production env. How do i enable debug mode on production? Isnt there a similar command to use form within tha app as `debug(True)` in Bottle ?

Comment: How are you running your app on production; through `gunicorn` or `uwsgi`? or simply through using `app.run()`? If you're using `app.run()` (which you shouldn't) you can pass the argument `debug` as shown in the example in my answer.

Although, as flask states, the app.run() should be used in development; even though you can debug on development rather than in production. ;)

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος does that help in any way?

Comment: I'm running my app under Apache + mod_wsgi. How should i enable debug mode in production? I dont use `app.run()` in production

Comment: This haven't proved helpful i'm afraid, because i tried both ways and the debug mode didn't activate.

Comment: Use `app.debug = True`

Comment: If that doesn't work, try the solution I added to my answer which uses werkzeug.

Comment: Neither with `app.debug=True` not with `werkzeug` i was able to enable debug mode. It surprises me because with Bottle all i have to do is `debug(True)`

Comment: I think you might be doing something wrong.. where did you place the werkzeug code?

Comment: Within my `files.py` Flask framework app like this `from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication  

application = Flask(__name__)
app = application
application = DebuggedApplication(app, True)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181160/discussion-between-julian-camilleri-and--).

Comment: I'am on chat but you don't seem to be logged in.

Answer (score 4):

Follow up with [Gil Sousa'S](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52605149/12568833) answer, if anybody is facing the same issue in windows

add these three lines in you code in you file,

```
app.config['ENV'] = 'development'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['TESTING'] = True
```

And also in the `cmd` or in your `anaconda prompt` type these commands to set up the debugging mode,

```
$ set FLASK_ENV=development 
$ set FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

and don't forget to pass `debug=True` inside `app.run()` as a argument.

PS: if you are following this answer, FYKI,  now flask apps are using the command `$set FLASK_APP=app.py`  then `$FLASK run` to run a flask app. This is only for windows for Linux use `export` instead of `set`.

Answer (score 1):

With version 1.0 of Flask, you can set environment variables to be auto imported when you run the flask command, you need to have installed `python-dotenv` though.

Then you can just create a new file in your top level directory named `.flaskenv` and set your environment variables in it:

```
FLASK_APP=run.py
FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

Answer (score 1):

In the flask library, you can enable the built-in debug mode using the following steps.

Step 1: Create a virtual environment (a best practice) in your project file:

```
python -m venv webserver
```

Or, using python3

```
python3 -m venv webserver
```

where the webserver denotes the location of the virtual environment and the folder will be saved as the "webserver".

A best practice is to use the folder name as "venv".

Step 2: Using Windows Powershell, navigate to your project folder

```
cd "location of the project folder"
```

Step 3: Set the flask app variable to specify the python script name:

```
$env:FLASK_APP="server.py"
```

Step 4: Set the flask environment variable to specify the environment type as "development" to activate the debugger:

```
$env:FLASK_ENV="development"
```

Step 5: Activate the project's virtual environment:

```
venv\scripts\activate
```

Step 6: Run the flask application:

```
flask run
```

Comment: This above set of steps took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: So if you guys face a similar problem and couldn't find the solution: check out the official documentation.

Comment: Official python's flask documentation: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/

Comment: It was the $env I think, in powershell the set env didnt work like $env: did.  This FINALLY did it for me: $env:FLASK_DEBUG=1     Note I did the app(debug=True), app['DEBUG'] = True app.debug = True....needed that $env.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing a webapp using flask 2.0 in vs code.

I faced problems running my flask application. Here's what helped: - 
To run your flask application -

```
 C:\Users\hansr\OneDrive\Desktop\python_dev\postgresdemo> $env:FLASK_APP='main'
```

To set the Debug mode ON -

```
C:\Users\hansr\OneDrive\Desktop\python_dev\postgresdemo> $env:FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

Now, run your flask app -

```
C:\Users\hansr\OneDrive\Desktop\python_dev\postgresdemo> python -m flask run
```

[Reference](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/1881#issuecomment-425154463)

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```bash
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
# then 
flask run
```

With one line

```bash
FLASK_DEBUG=1 flask run
```